# Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool

Tags: magento, magento2

I am getting this error when upgraded my Magento website to 2.4.5-p1 & saving configuration in admin.

Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool, Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool::__construct(): Argument #3 ($publishers) must be of type array, null given, called in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

Can anyone tell me how to debug this which extension is creating problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this https://php.watch/versions/8.0/deprecate-required-param-after-optional for a possible explanation. If you upgraded from say M2.4.2 and were previously running PHP 7.4, but are now required to be on PHP 8.1 in M2.4.5, you will likely have several instances where you have to move optional parameters to come after the required parameters.